# Android studio failed resolution for AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have been working on this Android app that extracts content from an online article. I'm trying to fix this error for hours now, so I would really appreciate it if anyone can help.
I have seen some few similar questions but none of that is applicable for my app so I'm posting this. 
I don't know how to fix this error with AsyncTask.

<`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Image; at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl`>

These are the full error messages

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp, PID: 4446
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/awt/Image;
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.<clinit>(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:381)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.<init>(RuntimeTypeInfoSetImpl.java:63)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:128)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.createTypeInfoSet(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:84)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.<init>(ModelBuilder.java:162)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.<init>(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:92)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:444)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:292)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1138)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:162)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:262)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:249)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:456)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:656)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:599)
    at com.aylien.textapi.TextAPIClient.extract(TextAPIClient.java:102)
    at com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp.ArticleClass.articleExtract(ArticleClass.java:35)
    at com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp.ArticleClass.doInBackground(ArticleClass.java:62)
    at com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp.ArticleClass.doInBackground(ArticleClass.java:13)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
E/AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.awt.Image" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp-w8twusyP96c8nQsFdomFUA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp-w8twusyP96c8nQsFdomFUA==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp-w8twusyP96c8nQsFdomFUA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp-w8twusyP96c8nQsFdomFUA==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp-w8twusyP96c8nQsFdomFUA==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp-w8twusyP96c8nQsFdomFUA==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp-w8twusyP96c8nQsFdomFUA==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp-w8twusyP96c8nQsFdomFUA==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp-w8twusyP96c8nQsFdomFUA==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp-w8twusyP96c8nQsFdomFUA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp-w8twusyP96c8nQsFdomFUA==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp-w8twusyP96c8nQsFdomFUA==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp-w8twusyP96c8nQsFdomFUA==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp-w8twusyP96c8nQsFdomFUA==/lib/x86, /system/lib]] at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) ... 27 more Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location /data/app/com.example.chaudo.textsummarizingapp-w8twusyP96c8nQsFdomFUA==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method) at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:354) at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:101) at dalvik.system.DexFile.(DexFile.java:75) at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:394) at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:354) at dalvik.system.DexPathList.(DexPathList.java:164) at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:74) at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65) at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.(PathClassLoader.java:64) at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:73) at com.android.internal.os.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:88) at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:74) at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:40) at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:727) at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:810) at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:1032) at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2345) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5749) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

This is my code. I tested the articleExtract() function to make sure it works properly in a normal Java class, but it shows error when I tried to call it through AsyncTask in the MainActivity in Android Studio.

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        articleExtract();
        System.out.println(article);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TextAPIException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}



@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void s) {
    //Show the result obtained from doInBackground
    System.out.println(article);
}
```

In the Main Thread

```
        new ArticleClass(url).execute();
```

Comment: It looks like articleExtract() needs at least one package which is not part of Java for the Android environment. Please add the list of imported classes from your method.

Comment: You are using Image from awt in an Andriod app... Are you sure you didn't mean to use ImageView?